How do I keep people from editing my posts?
This is quite straightforward, but I cannot seem to find anyone else asking this: How do I keep people from making edits to the body of my posts?
While I somewhat see what Stack Overflow is going for by allowing other people to edit posts that aren't their own, it must have been clear from the outset that it's a terrible idea. There is a reason why no other website does this: it opens the door to weird and/or unhelpful edits. People could simply ask the original poster to make edits themselves, or it could be up to specific people to ask users to do so when a post is really badly written,... In any case, I don't want it and I find that it distracts from actual question-answering.

https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/08/in-defense-of-editing/

"it opens the door to weird and/or unhelpful edits" These kinds of edits are more likely to be made with users having less than 2000 reputation, which is why we have a review queue called "Suggested Edits" in place. Moreover, look at the plus side! It allows for grammatical fixes, dead link fixes and so much more!

You haven't heard of Wikipedia? That rather famously allows everyone to edit all the pages.

After having a look at the revision history of your posts, you appear to be the one making "weird and/or unhelpful" edits and rollbacks after other people do reasonable jobs of trying to clean up noise from your posts. You should be inviting peoples' edits, not trying to stop them.

"How do I keep people from editing my posts?" By making your posts on a site that is not Stack Overflow. Please read: Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?

You can prevent people from making edits to your posts by making them perfect and in line with site guidelines. If there's nothing to edit, people can't make edits.

Before you publish anything on any site, make sure you learn about the platform's licensing policy. Please note that by making a contribution to the site you are licensing the published content to the platform, which automatically grants review and revision rights to the holders of the licensed content. More information here.

"How do I keep people from making edits to the body of my posts?" You cannot. If users edit your contributions, there is a reason. "People could simply ask the original poster to make edits themselves." We could, but I suspect our requests would be ignored or declined. I have certainly asked authors to improve their questions and received some very rude responses. In fact, your edit to your last question decreased the quality of your question by adding the necessary commentary that was removed by another user.

It's clear you are using the edit system as you would submit posts to a forum, responding to or requesting questions to be closed instead of accepting the improvements to your question made by other users. Your track record on the quality of your questions isn't a great start.

You edited a question to request closure in order to prevent others from editing it. As SecurityHound pointed out, this is inappropriate as an edit. In addition, closing your question does not prevent others from editing it. Anyone who can edit your question before the closure can make an edit after the closure just as fine. Having a closed question also counts against you and may bring you closer to a question ban. I suggest not doing that again.

I can't reply to individual people so I'll say this: the majority of the edits made to my posts made them less understandable. I am fine with improvements, but that hasn't happened much in practice.

And with regards to Wikipedia: Wikipedia has a very robust system to fight vandalism.

Actually, you're now the one committing vandalism by rolling back your questions to revisions that contain a bunch of unneeded cruft. Do you think Wikipedia would allow you to edit in things like "I am a beginner so please have mercy, but feedback is welcome"?

Pointing out that I am a beginner has the purpose of informing the people answering the posts that the poster is a beginner and can't be held to high standards.

@AengusBall as far as answerers are concerned sentences like "I am a beginner" and similar provide no useful information and are summarily ignored. What answerers might find useful is someone demonstrating knowledge (or the lack thereof)  of a particular concept from the text of their question.

Also: "Wikipedia has a very robust system to fight vandalism" Stack Overflow also has a system to fight vandalism, in fact some community members (not staff or the company) have even built bots for this purpose.

"I can't reply to individual people" - you can if you ping them by typing @ followed by their username with no spaces, as Abdul did in his comment. Note that you can only ping one person per comment. "Pointing out that I am a beginner has the purpose of informing the people answering the posts that the poster is a beginner and can't be held to high standards." - as far as I'm aware, the same question standards apply to everyone on Stack Exchange, regardless of their experience level.

"he majority of the edits made to my posts made them less understandable." - no, no they have not. Unless you're counting your rollbacks as edits. I genuinely can't understand how you can possibly see things this way. "Pointing out that I am a beginner has the purpose of informing the people answering the posts that the poster is a beginner and can't be held to high standards." No, it doesn't. First off, it does not matter to us that the poster is a beginner. Second, yes, you can, and are. This site is not a discussion forum.

Said system allows for edits that make the question harder to answer. That's the reason for my post.

"Wikipedia has a very robust system to fight vandalism." So does [so]; part of that is the ability to rollback said edits, another is that we have a review system so that those with <2k reputation can't just change content. We also have moderators who deal with exceptional cases, who can lock posts if it's needed to stop anyone editing them temporarily (not to fulfil your request you ask here) or in extreme cases suspend a user who has has vandalised multiple posts and/or hasn't stopped after being reached out to.

"Said system allows for edits that make the question harder to answer." Can you elaborate on how removal of text the community classifies as "noise" made the question harder to answer? Why does knowing your "programming level" isn't advanced make it easier to answer? How does telling us you're not familiar with the technology make it easier for others to answer your question? HOo does telling is the question you are using Python make it easier to answer when we can already see you are from the code that that you have tagged [[tag:python]] and [[tag:python-3.x]]?

It's context. Context is not noise.

I am sure that my posts can be improved, but removing context is counter-productive.

The experience you have is irrelevant to others; it's not context. We, the community, would answer the question the same if you have 10 seconds or 10 years of experience.

I made a post which ultimately came to be because I made a silly mistake. It was my job to make sure that it wasn't the case and I failed at that. What happened next is a case for the relevance of mentioning that I am a beginner: people started writing passive-agressive comments and repeating what others had said. One even quoted and linked to the older version of the post that pointed out that I am a beginner, saying something like "this is likely due to the lack of experience you mentioned". I wrote that I am a beginner precisely so people would be more patient. It's no rocket surgery.

Adding noise to your posts such as your experience level is a good way to drive answerers away and attract downvotes to your posts. Stick to the point and don't add unnecessary "context".

"passive-agressive comments" "would be more patient [but aren't now]" There is no justification to think these negative things.

@Dharman Do you have any example of a person other than you and me, asking a question in a compliant, yet reader-friendly way?

@philipxy I didn't roll back any edits after reading the answers to my post. Maybe the timing made it seem that way because my post made people look at the edit history of my SO submissions and roll back my repairs.

Sorry Aengus but I don't know what you are asking of me.

@Dharman examples of posts that are in line with the community standards people are talking about.

Maybe just look at the top scoring questions for examples. They have usually been curated well enough. https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Votes

Ok, thanks (am I allowed to say that?)

@AengusBall Except old posts were subject to lower standards (both rules & readers) so maybe look at good recent posts.

In a comment yes, because comments are generally meant to be temporary. Though on Meta it's slightly different.


This is quite straightforward, but I cannot seem to find anyone else asking this

That's hopefully because other people read the Help Center article which clearly explains the related policy.

How do I keep people from making edits to the body of my posts?

You don't, because it is a deliberately designed feature of the site.

While I somewhat see what Stack Overflow is going for by allowing other people to edit posts that aren't their own, it must have been clear from the outset that it's a terrible idea.

Well, no; we generally think it's proven itself to be a quite good idea. It's been almost 16 years now, by the way. Everyone's had ample time to reconsider and nobody has brought any serious arguments against the feature that are more substantial than "my post was edited and I don't like the change".

There is a reason why no other website does this: it opens the door to weird and/or unhelpful edits.

No, this is completely incorrect. In reality, countless other websites do it. You might have heard of one of the bigger ones. There are literally multiple competing off-the-shelf software solutions created specifically so that people can make websites that work that way.
We in fact rein it in considerably by requiring review and approval for edits submitted by users below 2000 reputation.

People could simply ask the original poster to make edits themselves, or it could be up to specific people to ask users to do so when a post is really badly written,

There is, by design, no direct message system here, so that would require using comments that would have to be cleaned up later, creating extra burden. Delegating the responsibility for asking is absurd, adding bureaucracy for no benefit. Besides, most people wouldn't make the changes, but it's important for the quality of the site that they get made.
But more importantly, what you've missed is:

... In any case, I don't want it

Sorry. To be blunt, you aren't the one who gets to make the decision. When you post here you license your content both to the company that operates the site, and to the public.

and I find that it distracts from actual question-answering.

If you think an edit made your post worse, it is your responsibility to a) demonstrate how, and b) understand the process for contesting an edit.
However, edits such as this one which remove noise are perfectly in keeping with policy, and make your question better - i.e., more in line with the site's standards and goals as described on the tour and in How to Ask (and How to Answer).
Because the question isn't there simply so that you can get an answer. It's there to help build a useful, searchable Q&A reference for everyone.

In most situations, you don't prevent others from editing your post.
Remember, this isn't a personal help site, but rather a question and answer site, where the goal is to craft well-constructed, focused and clear questions that can then receive well-constructed, focused and clear answers, questions and answers that are helpful to all. So for this reason, the site allows "trusted users" those with enough reputation, to be able to edit others posts, and allows newer users to propose edits that are then reviewed by trusted users. Most edits are made in an effort to make a question clearer and better formatted, to try to make it a better question for the site.
There are exceptions, of course, such as when someone strives to completely change the meaning of a question, or tries to inject rude or inappropriate content. For this, you would likely need to flag the moderators.

What is a better place for me to ask for help, where people having a similar issue can see the help I got and benefit from it?

@AengusBall This is the place to get SO help & there is meta.SE for all-sites help. But learn how to google using 'site:' so you can search in a site's /help pages & meta site Q&A & similarly both for meta SE: site:stackoverflow.com/help site:meta.stackoverflow.com site:meta.stackexchange.com . Also read all the help pages for a site. And SO help has a list of SO FAQ Q&A.

That's not what I asked about, but thanks for your time anyway.

What you aren't understanding here is that "me to ask for help" and "people having a similar issue can see the help I got and benefit from it" are at cross purposes. Asking a question that can better help others requires accepting that it is not about you.

You can't really prevent people from making edits to your posts as that would go against the core principle of the site. Stack Overflow is community-driven collaborative site. People must be able to freely edit posts to perfect them.

@aen The edits made by community were not vandalism. Your rollbacks are a form of vandalism but I see you just disagree with community standards so they're not malicious rollbacks. However as explained here, the edits are perfectly inline with our guidelines so please don't roll them back again.
